# How to restrict access to Keycloak admin console to a specific IP/IP range?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

Is there any way to restrict the access to the keycloak admin console by IP / IP Range? I have deployed the Keycloak in Azure Kubernetes that uses Nginx Ingress controller. So, I tried to restrict as highlighted below

[image]

but it blocks everything. I would assume that Ingress receives the incoming request from the Azure Kubernetes Load balancer so it does not consider the client IP to allow access.

How do I restrict the access to the keycloak admin console by IP / IP Range?

**Update#1:**
I believe that the above configuration to restrict the path by the IP / IP Range is effective expect that it redirects the coming request to a non-existing location

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [30/Aug/2023:15:42:25 +0000] "GET **/admin/** HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 507 0.000 [-] [] - - - - bfbe1faa35dcc40e82e5e22bd557cf96

2023/08/30 15:42:25 [error] 1171#1171: *6809656 **"/usr/local/nginx/html/admin/index.html"** is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 173.32.206.145, server: account.qa.oly.nova-x.co, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/2.0", host: "xxxx"
```

I was expecting this to apply just the IP based filter but not change the existing behaviour.

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loadBalancerSourceRanges` on the service as [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#restrict-inbound-traffic-to-specific-ip-ranges).

To restrict traffic for a certain path use `location-snippet` instead of `server-snippet` as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73061277/nginx-ingress-controller-ip-restriction-for-certain-path).

Comment: I want to restrict only the /admin/xxx path while rest of the path should be accessible

Comment: just updated the answer.